# What would be a good Apache2 web server configuration given the resources?

Tags: server, apache2, php

I am trying to figure out how to calculate and implement a good Apache2, MPM Event, PHP-FPM configuration on a VPS with dedicated resources as follows:

- 64 GB RAM
- 32 vCPUs

The server would be mainly responsible for processing and serving the PHP output, all static files are on another server.

All PHP processes are below 2MB of RAM and are executed nearly instant.
There are no other services on the server except the system ones (Running Ubuntu 20.04)

What would be a good Apache2 web server configuration given the resources to handle maximum possible users?

Comment: Not really a Ubuntu question. I would be looking into an Apache support site for an answer,

Comment: You are completly right, but I felt like would be the right thing to ask through my fellow Ubuntu fans which most probably have some experience with this and they would be willing to share their thought on this.

Comment: That's ... remarkably over-powered given the description you just provided. I have LAMP-based systems that service 15K requests per second running on a lot less. How much traffic are you dealing with?

Comment: @matigo  about 3.5M requests / day, but obviously most of the them are during business hours and are not dispersed throught that period. Anyway the problem on the system load is not the web server itself is the DB that handles a lot of transactions. I was just trying to figure out what would be the best config for the setup involving Apache2, MPM Event, PHP-FPM for the given config.

Comment: Experience has taught me that multiple web servers are better than one big one. With regards to the DB, this really comes down to how the application is written. The busiest systems I've worked on (an LMS for an international school) use a group of read-only DBs, and write to a primary DB that replicates data to the read-only DBs. This was possible because the LMS allows for separate read and write DB servers. Many applications do not. That said, without knowing *a lot more* about your needs, this question may not be answerable without a whole lot of opinion ... which is frowned upon here 

Comment: @matigo you are completly right. I was just trying to learn more about how to perfect the configuration for those services and what would be a good approach and how should I calculate all those variables as well as what should I take in consideration.